# How to implement custom UAC privilege UI?

Tags: windows-7, uac

When deleting a file in Windows Explorer (Windows 7), if admin privileges are required to delete the file, this dialog is displayed:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this kind of effect in my app?

Currently I am launching a process 'as administrator' to perform the same sort of action (replacing a file rather than deleting it), so the user is shown the generic UAC dialog, asking:

*"Do you want to allow the following program to make changes to this computer?"*

Is the kind of helpful UI shown by Explorer (as opposed to the generic UAC dialog) possible in a 3rd party app?

I'm guessing no, since it would allow 3rd parties to elevate privileges in a sneaky way.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Button_SetElevationRequiredState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761865%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to add the shield to the button. When the user pushes the button, [use the COM elevation moniker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create the helper object.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on setting the shield icon. I ended up using SendMessage, because I didn't have the right #defines to use that function/macro (and I didn't want to get into faffing around with #define _Win32 whatever).

Comment: I can't use COM, so am just running a copy of the exe as admin, with some special cmdline options instructing it to 'do the admin stuff'.

Comment: The shield icon is just an alert to the user that "If you push this button, somebody will ask you for permission to elevate, so don't be surprised." One way of asking for elevation permission is to use COM, but the command line works too.

Comment: Interestingly, Windows tends to show this shield even when there will be no UAC prompt. They didnt go the extra mile to hide the shield when a UAC prompt is not going to appear (due to system settings). - Presumably because everyone's supposed to be running with UAC enabled, and it'd complicate the source for not much benefit.

Answer (score 2):

The default setting on Windows 7 is for most system components to not show the UAC dialog.

If you change your setting to always prompt, you will see that clicking Continue in the Explorer dialog would create the normal UAC prompt.

As a non-system binary, your code would always prompt except at the most lenient UAC setting (never prompt.)

Comment: Yes, that's true: you can display the elevation entry button (Continue in this case) in any UI you want, but elevation process will always show you the system confirmation prompt no matter whether you start a new process or create an elevated COM object.